# Why UserControl isn't filling VerticalContentAlignment 'Stretch'?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Here is the parent Xaml:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" /><!-- Should stretch vertically -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- Menu definition removed for brevity -->
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               LastChildFill="True">
        <ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Designer}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      Background="YellowGreen"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

The `ItemsSource` binding is to an `ObservableCollection`. When the view is added to the collection, it gets updated in the main shell (view). Here is the `UserControl` that is added:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Prototype.StateMachineDesignerApp.Views.ProjectDesigner"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Prototype.StateMachineDesignerApp.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             Margin="0">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0"
                BorderBrush="DimGray"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Background="LightSlateGray"
                Margin="1" />
        <Border Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Column="0"
                        BorderBrush="DarkGoldenrod"
                        BorderThickness="1" />
                <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                <Border Grid.Column="2"
                        BorderBrush="DarkGoldenrod"
                        BorderThickness="1" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The `UserControl` is not filling the entire vertical space:
[image: user control image]

`Row[1]` of the outermost `Grid` is stretching vertically as is evidenced by the `ItemsControl.Background` filling the area.

For reference, this is what I am expecting: 
[image]

For what its worth, I've looked at numerous questions on SO regarding this exact issue but none of the solutions seem to help. Then again, none of the examples I saw used an `ItemsControl` with binding.

Comment: Since when are we not having WPF questions allowed? Has there been some change on SO that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong with what you got, it's fine from my end. I do see a Grid.Row defined on the parent though....any chance the parent of that one has that row set to Auto height or anything? I'd look further up.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the down vote. It is the vote to close that concerned me (probably both by the same person). Anyway, I will add the entire parent grid definition.

Comment: @ChrisW.: Updated with outermost grid definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `ItemsControl` throw all of our items into a vertically aligned `StackPanel` by default. It's very easy to change though, since the `ItemsControl` allows you to change which panel type is used to hold all the items.

```
<ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Designer}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  Background="Transparent">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <Grid />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: !!WOW!! ... this could use better documentation. Fixed!